# Trying to change the textview on another fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

So I have two fragments and I am trying to change the values of some textViews from a RecyclerView in one of the fragments to the other. The recycler view reads data from a json file and I am trying to set the TextViews according to the value of the recycler view but when I set the code to change the text in the onClick method of the recyclerView, my app doesn't run.

Here is the code.

```
    import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import android.widget.TextView
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.observe
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import com.example.currencyconverter.R


class CurrenciesFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
    private lateinit var recycler: RecyclerView
    private lateinit var countryName: TextView
    private lateinit var amountConverted: TextView


    companion object {

        fun newInstance() = CurrenciesFragment
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_currencies, container, false)

        recycler = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView)
        recycler.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(context)

        countryName = view.findViewById(R.id.selected_country)
        countryName.text = ""
        amountConverted = view.findViewById(R.id.converted_amount)
        amountConverted.text = ""



        return view
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)

        viewModel.country.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, {
            recycler.adapter = CountriesAdapter(it)
        })
       
    }

    private inner class CountriesViewHolder(view: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {

        private lateinit var phrase: Phrase
        private val countryText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_textView)

        init {
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
        }

        override fun onClick(v: View?) {
            countryName.text = phrase.name

        }

        fun bind(phrase: Phrase) {
            this.phrase = phrase
            countryText.text = phrase.name

        }
    }


private inner class CountriesAdapter(private val list: List<Phrase>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CountriesViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CountriesViewHolder {
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false)
        return CountriesViewHolder(view)
    }

    override fun getItemCount() = list.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: CountriesViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(list[position])
    }
}

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        menu.clear()
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

it is not a good practice to change the textview directly from the RecycelerView, instead I suggest you to put a lambda callback into the Adapter and the ViewHolder that will listen from the fragment.

Change Adapter code:

```
private inner class CountriesAdapter(private val list: List<Phrase>, private val textChanged: (text: String) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<CountriesViewHolder>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): CountriesViewHolder {
        val view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false)
        return CountriesViewHolder(view, textChanged)
    }
```

And the ViewHolder logic to:

```
private inner class CountriesViewHolder(view: View, val textChanged: (text: String) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view), View.OnClickListener {

    private lateinit var phrase: Phrase
    private val countryText: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.country_textView)

    init {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this)
    }

    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        textChanged.invoke(phrase.name)
    }

    fun bind(phrase: Phrase) {
        this.phrase = phrase
        textChanged.invoke(phrase.name)
    }
}
```

Inside your fragment add this new method:

```
private fun onTextChanged(text: String) {
    // Change TextView
}
```

And change the way you are constructing your adapter to include the lambda function:

```
CountriesAdapter(it, ::onTextChanged)
```

This is a common practice when working with RecyclerView.